# Creating constructors using "this" instead of simply returning an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

My knowledge of words might not be sufficient to find this by myself the explanation on the www. So please excuse me if this might be a duplicate.

I'm currently trying to figure out why we use "this" in a function constructor instead of simply returning an object?

E.g. this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf1qphu9/4/)

```
// Using this inside function
function Student1(first,last) {
    this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.display = function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  };
}

const harry = new Student1("Harry", "Potter");

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = harry.display();

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += "<br>";


// Returning object
function Studen2(first,last){
    return {
    firstName: first,
    lastName: last,
    display(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  };
}

const ron = new Student1("Ron", "Weasley");

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += ron.display();
```

Anyone mind to explain or guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will want to define the object methods on the class prototype, so that they don't have to be reinstantiated every time you create a new instance of the class, e.g.:

```
function Student1(first,last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
}

Student1.prototype.display = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

const harry = new Student1("Harry", "Potter");

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = harry.display();
```

If you just return an (anonymous) object, it won't have a prototype and you'll have to define the function every time the construction function gets called.

Also, in your example:

```
harry instanceof Student1 // true
ron  instanceof Student2 // false
```

So you can't use instanceof.

Comment: Okay you answered one question but created a new one. You already tried to explain why, but I didn't understand it (Sorry for my dumbness). Why is it better to use "Student1.prototype.display = ..." instead of creating it inside the function?

Comment: It's more efficient. Using prototype, the function only lives once, regardless of how many instances you have of the class (even if there's 0). When creating it inline, memory has to be allocated for each and every instance of the class you create.

Comment: Does this only happen for the toString method or generally for every method?

Comment: For every method

Answer (score 2):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works with the prototype of the instanciable function, whereas the simple object has another prototype in the chain of prototypes. It has not an own prototype of the instanciable function.

You could add a new method to the prototype and watch the difference.

```js
// Using this inside function
function Student1(first,last) {
    this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.display = function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  };
}

const harry = new Student1("Harry", "Potter");

Student1.prototype.morning = function () { return 'good morning ' + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; };

console.log(harry.morning());



// Returning object
function Studen2(first,last){
    return {
    firstName: first,
    lastName: last,
    display(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  };
}

const ron = new Student1("Ron", "Weasley");

Student2.prototype.morning = function () { return 'good morning ' + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; };

console.log(ron.morning());
```